# Is there any standalone pgp implementation in python?

Tags: python, gnupg

By 'standalone' I mean a module that allows my application to manage its own database of keys rather than resourcing to the one associated to the user account of the operative system where it runs?

I red python-gnupg's docs, if I understood it correctly it relies on the user local keys database.

I'd be happy with a solution that would work on linux. Support for other platforms has low priority at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [python-gnupg](http://code.google.com/p/python-gnupg/) both arguments are possible, *keyring* and *gnupghome*.

The bonus for the home dir approach is, that not only another (public) keyring is used, but you'll use all files in that dedicated directory. If it doesn't exist, it will be created and populated on creation of the gnupg.GPG instance - nice and sane.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [python-gnupg](http://packages.python.org/python-gnupg/#getting-started) you can use its `GPG()` constructor with `keyring` argument:

> keyring (defaults to None) If specified, the value is used as the name
>   of the keyring file. The default keyring is not used.

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me the right direction. But after reading that link and googling a bit more, I believe what I have to do is pass a diferent location as gnupg homedir to that same constructor. But I would sill like someone to confirm this.

Comment: No, in Python you can use keyword arguments and `GPG()` constructor works this way. You can write `gpg = GPG(keyring='my_keyring')`